# Missing Friend: Gone Birdwatching

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

I'm trying to get ahold of my old pal Felix. The last I knew he was travelling the US, so I wandered around - but it's a very big place! I did bump into his son in Milwaukee. He told me that Felix left for a birdwatching holiday, but unfortunately never told his son where! Felix did leave this note behind though:

LEPSPCIEIURLICAOTAL-CEUSCLOAELEDAIIPCTNNS-DOMTRIUASRGURISUT

Where on earth can I find my friend?!

Comment: Is this one or three different puzzles?

Comment: No hints yet - I'll give it a few days first.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Felix is visiting:

> Three states identified by their state bird:

> LEPSPCIEIURLICAOTAL -> Maine: POECILE ATRICAPILLUS (Chickadee)

> CEUSCLOAELEDAIIPCTNNS -> Louisiana: PELECANUS OCCIDENTALIS (Brown pelican)

> DOMTRIUASRGURISUT -> Wisconsin: TURDUS MIGRATORIUS (American robin)

Comment: I'm actually a bit surprised that [rot13] bayl bar fgngr unf gur puvpxnqrr nf vgf fgngr oveq,[/rot13] given how common it is.

Comment: Actually _guerr fgngrf unir gur nzrevpna ebova nf gurve fgngr oveq, ohg bayl bar bs gurve nooerivngvbaf yrnqf gb n inyvq pbhagel_, but is also _uvagrq ng ol jurer uvf fba yvirf_.